# USDZ: Are seperate Ambient Occlusion bitmaps supported?

Tags: export, file-format

I try to export my models to USDZ. All works well so far, but I've one question:

Is there a way to export seperate Ambient Occlusion bitmaps, that are multiplied in the object material by using the Color Mixer Node?

For example: When exporting to GLB, you can add a glTF Settings group node in the material and the ao bitmap will be exported then. But is there a also solution for USDZ files?

Any ideas? Thank you!

I'm working in Blender 3.6.2